# How I can get my visual studio IDE background as transparent?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to make my Visual Studio IDE as `transparent` or `semi-transparent` is there any theme available for this ?

Just like this (I know this is shell but I want same background for VS). I m using Visual Studio '13. I did lot of search but i couldn't find anything.

Suggest me the way if you know how can I make this using code if you aware about it.

[image]

Comment: It seems impossible even by code as Visual Studio is itself is a huge plugin system, composed of hundreds of extensions (from Visual Studio dev team, from other teams at Microsoft, and from 3rd parties, etc.). This implies hundreds different windows to make transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid but at the moment there is nothing with visual studio IDE or Theme which is provided or supported such feature.

Comment: Is there any way to get it done by development , I mean by code ?

Answer (score 0):

Search Windows Opacity in Visual Studio Extensions. Or download it below. The opacity ranges from 0-255 with 0 being completely transparent.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=skacekachna.win-opacity

Answer (score 0):

Checkout following two extensions:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pengweiqhca.transparency

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-593793.MoeIDE

the latter one built-in transparent themes based on the vanilla `Light` and `Dark` themes.

Also you can always use these extensions to build your own theme color palette:

VS2022: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=idex.colorthemedesigner2022

VS2019: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.ColorThemeDesigner

VS2015: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.VisualStudio2015ColorThemeEditor

Comment: https://github.com/Meowtrix/MoeIDE/issues/28#issuecomment-1387152189